# What do these font-shape warnings mean?

Tags: fonts, warnings

When I am compiling my document with pdflatex I get the following errors:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/m/n' in size <5.5> not available
(Font)              size <5> substituted on input line 50.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OML/cmm/m/it' in size <5.5> not available
(Font)              size <5> substituted on input line 50.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OMS/cmsy/m/n' in size <5.5> not available
(Font)              size <5> substituted on input line 50.
```

What do these warnings exactly mean? The area where I think they are coming from is enclosed with `{\fontsize{11}{12}\selectfont   }`. Also, the line number seems to be the place where a macro is called, and not the place in the macro where this is occuring.

How can I fix these warnings?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

A size substituation of 0.5pt is harmless, but if you want to avoid it load the fix-cm package:

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}
\fontsize{11pt}{12pt}\selectfont $a^2$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have replacements 2.5pt to 5pt using `minionpro` package.  `fix-cm` fixes the error messages, but I see no difference in the output.  Can it be used for `minionpro` anyway, since `fix-cm` package is named "Permit Computer Modern fonts at arbitrary sizes"?

Comment: @Pygmalion fix-cm fixes the computer modern (cm) fonts. It has no effect on minion-pro.