# xfrac + siunitx gives me a font warning

Tags: fontsize, warnings, siunitx, xfrac

I'm using `mathpazo` and the AMS math packages, and I just started using `xfrac` for the `\sfrac` command. However, now when I use `\sfrac` (or when I set `siunitx` to use it), I get this output:

> LaTeX Font Warning: Size substitutions with differences up to 4.40074pt have occurred.

How can I fix whatever's happening here, and prevent these warnings?

---

(Additional information)
I'm using Mac OS X 10.7.2, with MacTeX 2011 and TextMate.

> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011) (format=pdflatex 2011.10.22)

The `siunitx` version is 2.3h (2011/10/14)

This short document alone produces the warning:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx, xfrac}

\begin{document}

\[ \sfrac{123}{456} \]

\end{document}
```

When I remove `siunitx`, I no longer see the warning. The exact warning messages are as follows (In some cases, I only get the last message):

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/m/n' in size <3.49998> not available
(Font)              size <5> substituted on input line 6.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OML/cmm/m/it' in size <3.49998> not available
(Font)              size <5> substituted on input line 6.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OMS/cmsy/m/n' in size <3.49998> not available
(Font)              size <5> substituted on input line 6.

LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6.99997> on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <4.89995> on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <3.49998> on input line 6.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmss/m/n' in size <3.49998> not available
(Font)              size <5> substituted on input line 6.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmtt/m/n' in size <3.49998> not available
(Font)              size <5> substituted on input line 6.

[1

{/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./test.aux)

LaTeX Font Warning: Size substitutions with differences
(Font)              up to 3.25002pt have occurred.

 )
```

Comment: Please add a minimum working example (MWE) of a file that produces the errors you're encountering. Please also describe which version of TeX, and which operating system, you use. (I created a small file which loads the mathpazo, amsmath, and xfrac packages, using MacTeX 2011 on MacOSX 10.6.8 to create pdf output directly from the latex input, and have not encountered any of the problems you describe.)

Comment: @Mico: An MWE *without* [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) also doesn't produce a warning.

Comment: @Mico: I've put up more information and an example. It seems to be directly related to `siunitx`, rather than `mathpazo` or `amsmath`.

Answer (score 9):

Adding packages `lmodern` or `fix-cm` removes the warning, at least. References: [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4824/what-do-this-font-shape-warnings-mean) and [here](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/presentations/beamer-warnings/).

Comment: I had the same problem with **xfrac** without **siunitx**. The package **fix-cm** solved the issue.

Comment: I also had an issue with `arevmath`+`siunitx` packages under the specific conditions that I was using 10pt and `\mathcal`. If I used 11pt, the warning went away; if I did not use `\mathcal`, the warning went away; if I called `\SI` _outside_ a math environment, the warning went away. Using `fix-cm` package seems to have removed the issue.

Comment: Also, `anyfontsize` package works.