# siunitx + fouriernc = Size substitutions with differences?

Tags: fontsize, siunitx, warnings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [xfrac + siunitx gives me a font warning](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32378/xfrac-siunitx-gives-me-a-font-warning)

This document (New Century Schoolbook font in `\SI`)

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\SI{1}{\metre\per\second}

\end{document}
```

produces this warning

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Size substitutions with differences
(Font)              up to 2.01195pt have occurred.
```

Additional information:
This does only happen with the NC font in `\SI` with `\per` ("power to the -1"). Outside of `\SI` this does not happen (for example `$a^{-1}$ does not produce the warning). This does only happen on the units, not on magnitudes (10^-1).

- Why does this happen?
- Does siunitx require another font size for powers? Why?
- How to fix this warning?

Comment: Load the `fix-cm` package. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32378/xfrac-siunitx-gives-me-a-font-warning

Comment: Thanks, this removes the warnings, but care to explain why this package works for the New Century font when it should fix problems in Computer Modern?

Comment: Not sure myself, but `siunitx` seems to rely on Computer Modern for certain symbols even when other font packages are loaded.

Comment: BTW, without `fix-cm` I *do* get a warning outside `tabular`. Please test again and, if true, edit your question.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. Maybe I did something different on the first run. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `siunitx` package jumps through a lot of 'hoops' to give the correct appearance of output as far as possible. That means quite a bit of font detection and math/text mode switching. The warning can be generated by an example such as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\ensuremath{^{\text{{\unboldmath$-1$}}}}
\end{document}
```

where you'll note that there is no change of font at all (without `\unboldmath` the warning is slightly different). That I know of, there should be no change in the fonts actually used in the output: a quick check shows that everything looks OK.

Comment: Thanks, but how does this solve the problem? It's just another example, a bit more "low-level" however. Why does your code produces the warning and what do you suggest to fix it?