# Errors from \sfrac (xfrac package): "missing number" and "illegal unit of measurement"

Tags: errors, xfrac

When I attempt to use `\sfrac` (from the `xfrac` package), multiple `missing number, treated as zero` and `illegal unit of measurement (pt inserted)` errors are generated.

Example document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{fix-cm} % Fixes warnings about missing fonts; see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32378/xfrac-siunitx-gives-me-a-font-warning

\begin{document}

Test $\sfrac{1}{2}$.

\end{document}
```

This generates eight errors, all at the location where `\sfrac` is used (half are "missing number" errors and the other half are "illegal unit" errors).

I'm using TexMakerX 2.1 and MikTeX 2.9. Any suggestions as to how this problem might be resolved would be appreciated.

EDIT: Here's the output from `\listfiles`, as requested:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
   xfrac.sty    2011/10/09 v2896 L3 Experimental split-level fractions
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/message (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/04/18 v1.20 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
l3keys2e.sty    2011/10/09 v2900 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
  xparse.sty    2011/10/09 v2900 L3 Experimental document command parser
   expl3.sty    2012/07/16 v3990 L3 Experimental code bundle wrapper
 l3names.sty    2012/07/16 v3990 L3 Namespace for primitives
l3bootstrap.sty    2012/07/15 v3986 L3 Experimental bootstrap code
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
l3basics.sty    2012/07/15 v3987 L3 Basic definitions
 l3expan.sty    2012/07/15 v3986 L3 Argument expansion
    l3tl.sty    2012/07/15 v3986 L3 Token lists
   l3seq.sty    2012/07/15 v3986 L3 Sequences and stacks
   l3int.sty    2012/07/15 v3986 L3 Integers
 l3quark.sty    2012/07/15 v3986 L3 Quarks
   l3prg.sty    2012/07/15 v3986 L3 Control structures
 l3clist.sty    2012/07/15 v3986 L3 Comma separated lists
 l3token.sty    2012/07/15 v3986 L3 Experimental token manipulation
  l3prop.sty    2012/07/15 v3986 L3 Property lists
   l3msg.sty    2012/07/15 v3986 L3 Messages
  l3file.sty    2012/07/15 v3986 L3 File and I/O operations
  l3skip.sty    2012/07/15 v3986 L3 Dimensions and skips
  l3keys.sty    2012/07/15 v3986 L3 Experimental key-value interfaces
    l3fp.sty    2012/07/15 v3986 L3 Floating points
   l3box.sty    2012/07/15 v3986 L3 Experimental boxes
l3coffins.sty    2012/07/15 v3986 L3 Coffin code layer
 l3color.sty    2012/07/15 v3986 L3 Experimental colour support
l3luatex.sty    2012/07/15 v3986 L3 Experimental LuaTeX-specific functions
l3candidates.sty    2012/05/12 v3633 L3 Experimental additions to l3kernel
textcomp.sty    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package
  ts1enc.def    2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
xtemplate.sty    2011/10/09 v2900 L3 Experimental prototype document functions
  fix-cm.sty    2006/09/13 v1.1m fixes to LaTeX
  ts1enc.def    2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
supp-pdf.mkii
 ***********
```

Comment: No problems here using TeX Live 2013.

Comment: Neither here using MiKTeX 2.9.

Comment: Can you add `\listfiles` to your input and edit the `File list` from the `.log` file into your question.

Comment: Have you tried updating miktex? And Btw the is a much newer version og texmakerx (it is now called texstudio)

Comment: Might also be an idea to post the exact error message copied from the log

Comment: I tried updating MikTeX before posting this question, but the problem remained. The errors from the log are simply `! Missing number, treated as zero.` and `! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).` (followed in each case by `l.8 Test $\sfrac{1}{2}`).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because supplied example works with current (and older) tex distributions.

Comment: "Works on my machine" strikes me as a rather dubious reason for closure.