# Wrong scaled text size with relsize package and KOMA

Tags: koma-script, fontsize, relsize

The `relsize` package offers convenient ways to scale text in a document. The `\textscale` command allows to use arbitrary text sizes beyond the usual switches such as `\large` and `\small`. When KOMA script classes are used, however, the resulting size is messed up sometimes.

The following MWE should produce the letter M scaled from 10% to 99% of the current font size, `12pt`, in steps of one percent.

```
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4824/77970
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
%
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{relsize}
\KOMAoption{fontsize}{12}
\begin{document}

\renewcommand\RSpercentTolerance{0}
\newcount\foo
\foo=10
\loop
\textscale{0.\the\foo}{M}
\advance \foo +1
\ifnum \foo<100
\repeat

\end{document}
```

However, some of the letters are out of place, smaller letters following after larger letters. For instance, `\textscale{0.75}{M}` produces a larger M than `\textscale{0.76}{M}`, while it should be the other way around. Is there a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there is some incompatibility between the KOMA font size selection and the `relsize` package, although I cannot say what precisely. The issue is solved by simply loading the `relsize` package *after* setting the font size with `\KOMAoption{fontsize}{12}` as illustrated by the following MWE:

```
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4824/77970
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
%
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\KOMAoption{fontsize}{12}
\usepackage{relsize}
\begin{document}

\renewcommand\RSpercentTolerance{0}
\newcount\foo
\foo=10
\loop
\textscale{0.\the\foo}{M}
\advance \foo +1
\ifnum \foo<100
\repeat

\end{document}
```

As expected, now `\textscale{0.75}{M}` produces a smaller M than `\textscale{0.76}{M}`. This solution appears to work smoothly wihtout any other side-effects.

Comment: It is recommended to set `fontsize=12pt` in the class options: `\documentclass[fontsize=12pt]{scrartcl}`.